# ASP.NET Routing. How can i use Routing in a Generic Handler?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ashx, asp.net-routing, generic-handler

I tried to use ASP.Net's in the following generic handler, but i get this error at `Page.RouteData`

```
Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference
```

What i am doing wrong?

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="MainHandler" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Xml


    Public Class MainHandler : Implements IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

        Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

            Dim lng As String = Page.RouteData.Values("locale")

        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
            Get
                Return False
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
```

For any answers, please keep in mind that i am a newbie, and my tongue language is VB.NET :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Dim lng As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("locale")
```

Comment: You are permitted to accept your own answer. The answer could be improved by explaining how and why it fixed your problem. It may even garner a few up votes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.You  have to retrieve the route table and read from it.

```
Dim rd AS RouteData
rd = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context))

Dim val AS String
val = rd.Values["locale"].ToString()
```

Take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx) and [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)  for more details on routing.

Comment: @net i think i have an extra issue here... Type 'MainHandler' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Comment: I think you are implementing this wrong. Can you take a look at the links I put up.

Comment: @net I am sure i am implementing this wrong, since it is not working :( Actually i came here after reading the second link. I appreciate your help

Comment: This is a simpler link. http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/ .

Comment: I have a feeling that i am toooo newbie! I do not have problem implementing the ASP.NET Routing in .aspx pages. I have problem implementing the asp routing within a generic handler. So i can use that "page" thing, into the generic handler...

Comment: ok, its tough to explain the whole thing here. but if you are just looking to the value, you can do context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["locale"]) instead of using page.RouteData in the processrequest function. checkout this link for more details. http://petesdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/generic-handlers-and-aspnet-routing.html .

Comment: And that is getting me to the post above... VB.NET & newbie :)

Comment: From the http://petesdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/09/generic-handlers-and-aspnet-routing.html link, it looks like you need to implement an `IRouteHandler` that will create an instance of your `IHttpHandler`, and register that with the route.  (You might have done this already?  If so, please show...)  Then, in that route handler you need to grab the `RequestContext` in your implementation of `GetHttpHandler` and store it in an instance variable of your `IHttpHandler`.  *Then* you can use the `RequestContext` in your `IHttpHandler`.

Comment: The above stated a slightly different way - can you show how you're registering the route?